# How can I apply an effect to a sound to simulate hearing it underwater?

Tags: xna, sound, sound-effects

I'm using XNA 4.0 and trying to reproduce an "underwater effect" for every sound played.

How can I apply an effect to a sound, and what effect should I use to make it sound like as if the player is underwater while hearing it?

Comment: A low-pass filter might work, but I don't know how to do that in XNA.

Answer (score 2):

[DynamicSoundEfectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.dynamicsoundeffectinstance.aspx) might be a good start.

Load the sound into a buffer from a file, then apply a custom low-pass filter to it.

See [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/39943/adjust-treble-and-bass-on-audio-in-xna) for more detailed information on adjusting audio in XNA.